# python iterative loop gets slower as it continues

Tags: performance, for-loop, iteration

I have a for loop like

```
for tot in range(0,100000):
```

at first iterations it is quite fast but as it reaches toward the middle it gets extremely slow. I don't have such code lines that you say sth gets accumulated and gets large so it's computation takes longer.

It stays the same as the first iteration always, but gets processed slower.

Is it because each time tot goes from beginning of "range" to reach to the proper iteration, and as iterative method continues it takes longer to reach to middle of the "range"?

I have no idea why this happens!!!

Inside loop sample code:

```
for tot in range(0,nt):
    for k in range(0,nx):
        if k!=0 and k!=nx-1:
            for i in range(1,nz-1):
                phai0[i,k]=(1.0/dz**2)*(w0[i+1,k]-2.0*w0[i,k]+w0[i-1,k])+(1.0/dx**2)*(w0[i,k+1]-2.0*w0[i,k]+w0[i,k-1])
                phai1[i,k]=(1.0/dz**2)*(w1[i+1,k]-2.0*w1[i,k]+w1[i-1,k])+(1.0/dx**2)*(w1[i,k+1]-2.0*w1[i,k]+w1[i,k-1])
                phai2[i,k]=(2.0-Ncoef**2*dt**2)*phai1[i,k]-phai0[i,k]+1.0*(Ncoef**2)*(dt**2*1.0/dz**2)*(w1[i+1,k]-2*w1[i,k]+w1[i-1,k])

        if k==0:
            for i in range(1,nz-1):
                phai0[i,k]=(1.0/dz**2)*(w0[i+1,k]-2.0*w0[i,k]+w0[i-1,k])+(1.0/dx**2)*(w0[i,k+1]-2.0*w0[i,k]+w0[i,k-2])
                phai1[i,k]=(1.0/dz**2)*(w1[i+1,k]-2.0*w1[i,k]+w1[i-1,k])+(1.0/dx**2)*(w1[i,k+1]-2.0*w1[i,k]+w1[i,k-2])
                phai2[i,k]=(2.0-Ncoef**2*dt**2)*phai1[i,k]-phai0[i,k]+1.0*(Ncoef**2)*(dt**2*1.0/dz**2)*(w1[i+1,k]-2*w1[i,k]+w1[i-1,k])

        if k==nx-1:
            for i in range(1,nz-1):
                phai0[i,k]=(1.0/dz**2)*(w0[i+1,k]-2.0*w0[i,k]+w0[i-1,k])+(1.0/dx**2)*(w0[i,1]-2.0*w0[i,k]+w0[i,k-1])
                phai1[i,k]=(1.0/dz**2)*(w1[i+1,k]-2.0*w1[i,k]+w1[i-1,k])+(1.0/dx**2)*(w1[i,1]-2.0*w1[i,k]+w1[i,k-1])
                phai2[i,k]=(2.0-Ncoef**2*dt**2)*phai1[i,k]-phai0[i,k]+1.0*(Ncoef**2)*(dt**2*1.0/dz**2)*(w1[i+1,k]-2*w1[i,k]+w1[i-1,k])

    for N in range(0,N_inner_iteration):
        sum_max=0
        for k in range(0,nx):
            if k!=0 and k!=nx-1:
                for i in range(1,nz):
                    if i!=nz-1:
                        w21[i,k]=0.5*(dz**2)*(w20[i,k+1]+w20[i,k-1])/(dx**2+dz**2)+0.5*(dx**2)*(w20[i+1,k]+w20[i-1,k])/(dx**2+dz**2)-(0.5/(dx**2+dz**2))*(dx**2*dz**2)*phai2[i,k]
                    if i==nz-1:
                        w21[i,k]=1/(1+(p(k*dx,1)/(dx*p(k*dx,2)))+((2/p(k*dx,2)*(p(k*dx,1))**2-p(k*dx,0))/dz)+(p(k*dx,1)/dx/dz))*(((p(k*dx,1)/(dx*p(k*dx,2)))+(p(k*dx,1)/dx/dz))*w0[i,k-1]+(((2/p(k*dx,2)*(p(k*dx,1))**2-p(k*dx,0))/dz)+(p(k*dx,1)/dx/dz))*w0[i-1,k]-((p(k*dx,1)/dx/dz))*w0[i-1,k-1])

                    sum_max=sum_max+abs(w21[i,k]-w20[i,k])
                # w20[i,k]=w21[i,k]

            if  k==0:
                for i in range(1,nz):
                    if i!=nz-1:
                        w21[i,k]=0.5*(dz**2)*(w20[i,1]+w20[i,k-2])/(dx**2+dz**2)+0.5*(dx**2)*(w20[i+1,k]+w20[i-1,k])/(dx**2+dz**2)-(0.5/(dx**2+dz**2))*(dx**2*dz**2)*phai2[i,k]
                    if i==nz-1:
                        k=0.00000001
                        w21[i,k]=1/(1+(p(k*dx,1)/(dx*p(k*dx,2)))+((2/p(k*dx,2)*(p(k*dx,1))**2-p(k*dx,0))/dz)+(p(k*dx,1)/dx/dz))*(((p(k*dx,1)/(dx*p(k*dx,2)))+(p(k*dx,1)/dx/dz))*w0[i,k-2]+(((2/p(k*dx,2)*(p(k*dx,1))**2-p(k*dx,0))/dz)+(p(k*dx,1)/dx/dz))*w0[i-1,k]-((p(k*dx,1)/dx/dz))*w0[i-1,k-2])

                    sum_max=sum_max+abs(w21[i,k]-w20[i,k])

            if k==nx-1:
                for i in range(1,nz):
                    # w21[i,k]=w21[i,0]
                    # w20[i,k]=w21[i,k]
                    if i!=nz-1:
                        w21[i,k]=0.5*(dz**2)*(w20[i,1]+w20[i,k-1])/(dx**2+dz**2)+0.5*(dx**2)*(w20[i+1,k]+w20[i-1,k])/(dx**2+dz**2)-(0.5/(dx**2+dz**2))*(dx**2*dz**2)*phai2[i,k]
                    if i==nz-1:
                        w21[i,k]=1/(1+(p(k*dx,1)/(dx*p(k*dx,2)))+((2/p(k*dx,2)*(p(k*dx,1))**2-p(k*dx,0))/dz)+(p(k*dx,1)/dx/dz))*(((p(k*dx,1)/(dx*p(k*dx,2)))+(p(k*dx,1)/dx/dz))*w0[i,k-1]+(((2/p(k*dx,2)*(p(k*dx,1))**2-p(k*dx,0))/dz)+(p(k*dx,1)/dx/dz))*w0[i-1,k]-((p(k*dx,1)/dx/dz))*w0[i-1,k-1])

                    sum_max=sum_max+abs(w21[i,k]-w20[i,k])
                    # w20[i,k]=w21[i,k]

        w20[:]=w21[:]

        if (1.0/(nx*nz))*sum_max<0.0000001:
            break

    print (1.0/(nx*nz))*sum_max, "N=",N
    w0[:]=w1[:]
    w1[:]=w20[:]
    w_final[:,:,tot]=w1[:]

    for ordstep in range(1,num_of_orders+1):
        integ_sum2=0
        for zstep in range (0,nz):
            for xstep in range (0,nx):
                integ_sum2=integ_sum2+w1[zstep,xstep]*np.sin(ordstep*(k_z*1.0/m)*zstep*dz)*np.sin(ordstep*(k_x*1.0/n)*xstep*dx-omega*tot*dt)*dx*dz
        Amp[ordstep-1,tot]=4.0/(l*h)*integ_sum2/Ampref

    if tot%1==0:
        Ampsave=np.reshape(Amp[:,tot],(1,5))
        with open('test.csv', 'a') as file:
            np.savetxt(file,np.array(Ampsave))
    # np.save(outfile,Amp)
    oldcol = wframe
    wframe = ax.plot_surface(X, Z, w1, rstride=2, cstride=2)
    if oldcol is not None:
        ax.collections.remove(oldcol)
    plt.pause(.001)
    ax.set_xlabel('(X)')
    ax.set_ylabel('(Z)')
    ax.set_zlabel('$ W_{Numerical} $')
    plt.figure('Amplitude Evolution')
    plt.axis([0, 40000, -2, 2])
    plt.scatter(tot, Amp[0,tot])
    plt.scatter(tot, Amp[1,tot])
    print Amp[0,tot]
    plt.draw()
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0.)
    plt.title('Amplitude Evolution')
    plt.xlabel('Time[s]',fontsize=25)
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude',fontsize=25)
    plt.savefig("res.png", transparent = True, pad_inches=0)
    plt.show()
```

I have also changed all range to xrange and avoided using np. inside the loops by predefining them.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your code that's running inside the loop, as it is likely the culprit here.

Comment: @iMassakre  added the code

Comment: Where does the value of `N_inner_iteration` come from? Does it ever change while the loop executes?

Comment: no no it is a fixed value

Comment: Loops that slow down as the iteration count increases are a classic symptom of [Schlemiel the Painter-style algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm).

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Yes exactly that's what I supposed and also wrote end  of my post, but don't know which part causes this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Python2.7 ou Python3.x?

If you are using Python2.7 you should choose xrange generator:

```
for tot in xrange(0,100000): print tot
```

It will be faster for sequences large than this. :-)

Comment: I am using Pycharm 4.0.4